# Алгоритм Брезенхема c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Помогите найти ошибку в мейне, при вводе 1 10 3 6 откуда-то появляются числа 33 и 0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using std::vector;
void line(vector<vector<int>> matr,int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1){
  int dx = std::abs(x1 - x0);
  int dy = std::abs(y1 - y0);
  int error = 0, derr = dy;
  int y = y0;
  matr[x0][y0] = '*';
  for(int x = x0; x <= x1; ++x)
    {
      matr[x][y] = '*';
      error += derr;
      if(2*error >= dx)
      {
          y--;
          error -= dx;
       }
    }
}

int main()
{
  int x1, x2, y1, y2;
  std::cin >> x1 >> x2 >> y1 >> y2;
  vector<vector<int>> matr(x2, vector<int> (y2, -1));

  //line(matr, x1, x2, y1, y2);
  for(int i = 0; i < y2; ++i)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < x2; ++j)
        std::cout << matr[i][j] << ' ';
      std::cout << '\n';
    }


}
```

Comment: В `line` матрицу точно надо передавать по значению?...

Comment: @Harry, не точно))

Comment: @Harry, но выводит ошибку

Comment: переставили местами x,y (в main() у вас `m[y][x]`, а в line() `m[x][y]`). Попробуйте, лучше с++11 циклы: `for (auto&& row : matr) for (auto& p: row) p = '*';`

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы `'*'` печаталось как `*`, а не к примеру `42`, то используйте `char` тип, а не `int`.

Comment: Чтобы от segfault застраховаться, [можно `matr.at(y).at(x)` вместо `matr[y][x]` использовать](https://ideone.com/4gGvhU)

Comment: "...откуда-то появляются числа 33 и 0" **Где** "появляются числа"? О чем речь вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибок тут много. Во-первых, передавай вектор matr по ссылке, чтобы потом его по циклу for прогонять.

```
void line(vector<vector<char> > &matr,int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1)
```

Во-вторых, если видишь, я в угловых скобках поменял int на char, сделай так везде, где у тебя в угловых скобках стоит int.
В-третьих вместо

```
std::cout << matr[i][j] << ' '
```

нужно

```
std::cout << matr[j][i] << ' ' //i и j меняй местами
```

Если я правильно понял твою логику.
В-четвертых, убери нестрогое сравнение в цикле for функции line

```
  for(int x = x0; x < x1; ++x)//поменял <= на <
    {
      matr[x][y] = '*';
      error += derr;
      if(2*error >= dx)
      {
          y--;
          error -= dx;
       }
    }
```

Надеюсь, помог)

В пятых, прости, что сразу не сказал, имплементацию алгоритма на плюсах возьми другую.
https://prog-cpp.ru/brezenham/ вот отсюда.